# Cannot read property 'complete' of null - complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I would like to get [this effect](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZgqgJ) working on my webpage.

But I already tried this multiple times and failed every time. So, this is the reason why I am going to try it first on a local level. I copied everything you can see on the codepen.io webpage and replaced the both images with my pictures. Further, I added the id `id="coverart"` to the img and thats it.

But I get an error on this:

```
if (image.complete) {
```

The reason for it is:

> Cannot read property 'complete' of null

But if I type this in my console:

```
document.getElementById('coverart');
```

I get the element back:

```
<img id="coverart" src="https://gamekeys-shop.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/coverart.png">
```

So, it cannot be null... What could be the reason for it and how can I fix it?
[Here you can download the little html, css and js files.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzLxINxZFzovczIwRUVXcl93Q3c)

**EDIT:**

If you insert `alert(image)`, you will get null. If you replace this

```
if (image.complete) {
  start();
} else {
  image.onload = start;
}
```

with this

```
image.onload = start;
```

You will get the same null error... Why do I get null... It cannot be null?

Comment: @hsnbl `image.complete` return whether the image has been completely loaded or not. If it has, it returns `true`

Comment: @TobiasGlaus thanks for information :)

Comment: @Erik did you try to use $(document).ready(function(){ //your code here })

Comment: Yup that could be the possible solution. On codepen there's no need to wrap everything in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` or `$(function(){...});`. So try wrapping all of that code in one of these functions (they're identical)

Comment: @Erik did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible ways to improve it:
1) Just put your javascript file after the img tag.[image]

2) Or run you code only when document will be loaded.

Comment: Why? Where is the logic?

Comment: In your example you try to get the image tag, but the image element is not loaded yet, that's why you have null instead of element.

If you place javascript file after initialization of image element everything will be ok.

And as I have said before, you can use another way: just try `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your jquery definition onto bottom of body tag and use jquery `$(document).ready()` event like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var image = document.getElementById("coverart");
    if(image.complete){
        console.log("loaded");
    }
})
```

```html
<img id="coverart" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no need to wrap your code within a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` or `$(function(){...});` *on codepen*.
So try doing that. You need jQuery to do that. So just add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
```

to your HTML `head`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var image = document.querySelector('img');
  var imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var imageCanvasContext = imageCanvas.getContext('2d');

  ...

  imageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  imageCanvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  imageCanvasContext.drawImage(lineCanvas, 0, 0);
  }
});
```

Tried that for myself on localhost and it's working fine